# BackgroundWorker does not want to stop working

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker

I created a simple program for downloading files, downloads the first set and then starts downloading another and downloads files from the list.
But sometimes stops at 3 file and downloaded.
I investigated the previous download is not completed even when the file is downloaded to 100%.

```
Private Sub Download(ByVal Down As Integer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString("http://example.com/files/" + Convert.ToString(Down) + ".zip")
    TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Down)
    req = Net.WebRequest.Create(TextBox1.Text)
    resp = req.GetResponse
    req.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    download_size = resp.ContentLength
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = download_size
    Console.WriteLine(BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    On Error Resume Next
    downloaded_size = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(FlatTextBox1.Text + "\" + TextBox2.Text + ".zip").Length
    ProgressBar1.Value = downloaded_size
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        If Timer2.Enabled = False Then
            Timer2.Start()'Timer 5sec to to start function Download(x) and ProgressBar set to 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    On Error Resume Next
    Console.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text + " | " + FlatTextBox1.Text + "\" + TextBox2.Text + ".zip")
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(TextBox1.Text, FlatTextBox1.Text + "\" + TextBox2.Text + ".zip", "", "", False, 360000, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot get help here as long as you write On Error Resume Next code.

Comment: @HansPassant , I expected it to be a comment.
However it got there the reasons that I have uploaded to the server only 3 files.

Comment: I commented "On Error Resume Next" everywhere and when is downloading files 1,2 or 3 it's no stop by error - only 4 and high (becouse i haven't uploaded files - 404)

Comment: @Mubby Please see the first example of how to use a BackgroundWorker at [BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Does your code look anything like this?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to download files than using BackgroundWorker is **WebClient** with function **DownloadFileAsync**.
But it is necessary enable WebClient in the Toolbox.

```
Private Sub Download(ByVal Down As Integer)
    TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Down)
    Dim Adresa As String = "http://example.com/files/" + Convert.ToString(Down) + ".zip"
    WebClient1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Adresa), FlatTextBox1.Text + "\" + TextBox2.Text + ".zip")
End Sub

Private Sub WebClient1_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebClient1.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub WebClient1_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebClient1.DownloadFileCompleted
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    'Here place script to download next file..
End Sub
```